# error while building jenkins docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm trying to build jenkins docker image locally using the jenkins Dockerfile locally and I keep getting this error.

```
Step 17/34 : COPY init.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/tcp-slave-agent-port.groovy
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder028619870/init.groovy: no such file or directory
```

[Here's the Dockerfile that I am using.](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/587b2856cd225bb152c4abeeaaa24934c75aa460/Dockerfile)
And this is the build command I am using(Dockerfile is in the PWD) :

```
docker build -t jenkins-k8s .
```

Comment: Please share your Dockerfile - so we can help you.

Comment: I haven't modified Dockerfile yet. The file can be found in the link that I mentioned. Here's the same web link to the file: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/587b2856cd225bb152c4abeeaaa24934c75aa460/Dockerfile

Comment: From which path you are running this Docker command ? And check if init.groovy file exists in your system or not

Comment: @IshaaRora The command is being run in $PWD.  And the Dockerfile is present in $PWD.

Comment: I ran into same issue some days back. File or directory, when added somewhere in $PWD, worked for me. In your case, init.groovy should be there in $PWD. Is it available there?

Comment: Where do I find the missing files?
All the COPY commands don't work. COPY init.groovy was the first one!

Comment: It is present in same Git Repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in these Github Repo there is a file named **init.groovy**. 
And in the Dockerfile there is a Statement like

```
COPY init.groovy /SOME/PATH/IN/THE/CONTAINER
```

When you want to use this Dockerfile, you have to download the init.groovy as well. But there are more COPY Statements in these Dockerfile.

Dont know if you need such a big Dockerfile for your needs.

For our needs we just use the official ParentImage from DockerHub.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.73.3

USER root
ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > 
/etc/timezone

USER jenkins
```

You can change the Version and the Timezone for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend cloning the git repository before building the Dockerfile:

```
git clone https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker

cd docker 

git checkout 587b2856cd225bb152c4abeeaaa24934c75aa460  # Switch to the version you mentioned in the question.

docker build -t jenkins-k8s .
```

By doing so, you are guaranteed to have all the files that are required to build the Dockerfile.